# How to make a push button must be clickable to change value and make continue in PyQt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How to make a push button must be clickable in order to change a value and continue futher program.

I was trying to make a simple GUI where i want to print value from 1 to 100 through label widget.Another requirement is when the value in the loop is equal to multiple of 4(each_item %==0) i want to double it through pushButtonChange and print to the label.I have written code for it but program does not waits to change  value by clicking pushButtonChange.How to make program stop and wait for to click into push button and continues.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog,QApplication
from  verifygui import *
class MyForm(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui=Ui_Dialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButtonStart.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.show()
    def start(self):
        list1=list(range(100))
        # print(list1)
        for each_item in list1:
            if each_item%4==0:
                self.ui.pushButtonChange.clicked.connect(lambda:self.valueChanged(each_item))
            else:
                self.ui.label.setText(str(each_item))

    def valueChanged(self,each_item):
        new_value=each_item*2
        self.ui.label.setText(str(new_value))


if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    w=MyForm()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is not understood, explain yourself better

Comment: to display from 1 to 100 in label you would need Timer to execute function with delay (so it will display slower than normal loop) and this function will change value. You can't use `time.sleep()` and `for`-loop because it will freeze GUI.

Comment: @fulas thank you for answer .I just  wanted a GUI which  will stops in certain condition and waits for user to work done through push Button(dialog input etc.) and does work and continues to remaining work.If there any way to stop execution and wait for Push Button .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure if I understand problem but I put my code.

Button `Start` set first value in label or print in console "Already running"

Button `Change` add +1 to current value and miltiplicate *2 if value is divided by 4.
It will print in console `Not running` if `Start` was not pressed before or wen value will be 100 (it stops it and you have to use `Start` again)

It doesn't use `for`-loop because value is changed only when button is pressed.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class MyForm(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = QLabel(self, text="?")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.buttonStart = QPushButton(self, text="Start")        
        self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonStart)

        self.buttonChange = QPushButton(self, text="Change")
        self.buttonChange.clicked.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonChange)

        self.is_running = False
        self.current_item = 0

        self.show()

    def start(self):
        if not self.is_running:
            self.is_running = True
            self.current_item = 1
            self.label.setText(str(self.current_item))
        else:    
            print("Already running")

    def valueChanged(self):
        if self.is_running:
            self.current_item += 1
            if self.current_item % 4 == 0:
                self.label.setText(str(self.current_item * 2) + " <-- double")
            else:
                self.label.setText(str(self.current_item))
            if self.current_item >= 100:
                self.is_running = False
        else:
            print("Not running")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyForm()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

It is my first version. It use Timer to change value in label every 0.5ms (500ms).

It starts counting when you press `Start`. When you press `Change` and there is value divided by 4 then it multiplicate it *2

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QLabel, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

class MyForm(QDialog):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.label = QLabel(self, text="?")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)

        self.buttonStart = QPushButton(self, text="Start")        
        self.buttonStart.clicked.connect(self.start)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonStart)

        self.buttonChange = QPushButton(self, text="Change")
        self.buttonChange.clicked.connect(self.valueChanged)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.buttonChange)

        self.current_item = 0

        self.show()

    def start(self):
        self.current_item = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.valueUpdate)
        self.timer.start(500) # 500ms = 0.5s

    def valueUpdate(self):
        self.current_item += 1
        self.label.setText(str(self.current_item))

        if self.current_item >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()


    def valueChanged(self):
        if self.current_item is not None:
            if self.current_item % 4 == 0:
                new_value = self.current_item * 2
                self.label.setText(str(new_value))
        else:
            print("Not running")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyForm()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```